# Defining of time complexity of algorithm(log n or n)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
 int silly(int n, int m) {
 if (n < 1) return m;
 else if (n < 10)
  return silly(n/2, m);
 else
  return silly(n - 2, m);
}
```

Is this algorithm O(log n) or O(n) in terms of Big-Oh notation?

Answer (score 5):

If the optimizer is really good it's O(1). The code is equivalent to simply `return m`.

Taking it as given, we can discount the `if( n < 10 )` condition because that's a few iterations when n is small. We're looking for worst case when n is large.

That just leaves recursing into `silly(n - 2, m)` which is counting down every other integer. That's n/2 operations. We drop the constant making it O(n).